# 403 access denied to the website with proper login/pass through google script

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, authorization

```
var url = "https://web-site_name/page/?format=json&var_data-organization_dates&xlsexport=true";

   var payload =
   {
     "login" : "login",
     "password" : "pass",
   };

  var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "payload" : payload,
     "followRedirects" : false
   };

  var login = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://web-site_name/page/" , options);
  var sessionDetails = login.getAllHeaders()['Set-Cookie'];
  Logger.log(login.getAllHeaders());
```

here is the part of the code I try to use, to automate export of the data from web-site, i do have proper login and password and able to download file in json (opened in xsl) manually, I've got the address to the downloaded file in network in developer tools, but i have a problem on the first stage - when trying to authorize to the web-site - access denied. I've tried the code, given in answers on stackoverflow, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to make an url fetch request correctly, depends on the website you want to access and the authentication they uses

In the simplest case, your website requires HTTP basic authentification, in this case the correct syntax would be

```
var authHeader = 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(login + ':' + pass);
var options = {
  headers: {Authorization: authHeader}
}
```

- If your website uses a different authentication form, you might need to provide an access token.
- In any case: the authentication credentials go into `headers`, not into `payload`!
- `payload` is the data that you want to post = upload to the website.
- If you want export data from the website - that is download data - you do not need a `payload` and the correct method would be `get`, not `post`. Btw., if the method is `get`, you do not need to specify it.

Please see [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/third-party-apis#http_basic_authentication) for more information and samples.